# When using turbolinks (rails), sending multiple ajax request instead of one

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

Looking at the `firebug`, this line is the one causing this problem:

```
xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null )
```

in `jquery.js` file. Without remote: `true`, the `form` or `link_to` works fine with `turbolink` and also worked before including `turbolink`.

Comment: And, what exactly is your question? Try and be clear.

Comment: @simonmorley I have a form with remote: true, when i submit the form it sends multiple ajax requests(varies from 2 to 12). This happens when i use turbolinks. Also, it works fine when the particular page (with form) is reached directly through url or after a complete page load. The problem happens when the page with form is loaded through "turbolink get request".

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer after raising an issue in the github page, it was apparently because of using the javascript tag outside the head tag. Now after including the javascript tag within the head tag everything works smooth and fine.

Answer (score 3):

I have from time to time the same issue. And every time the problem was in multiple includes of javascripts files (in this case I think jquery is included more than once). Check this out